# I can't create a Desktop entry on Ubuntu that works - invalid desktop entry file

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, .desktop

I created a Desktop URL entry that worked once but when I tried to create a 2nd URL link using gedit on the desktop it fails.
I can't look at my original classic hits icon that works with gimp.
My failing `Country Roads.desktop` reads as

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name= Link to Country Roads
Type=Link
Exec=http://tune-in.com/radio/Country-Roads-s224628/

[Internet Shortcut]
URL=http://tune-in.com/radio/Country-Roads-s224628/
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.desktop` launcher doesn't look right, change it to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name= Link to Country Roads
Type=Link
URL=http://tune-in.com/radio/Country-Roads-s224628/
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Comment: When I responded I forgot to type the encoding line after Desktop Entry but that was in my entry. But I did removed the line [Internet Shortcut] but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @RobMit It's not just about removing the `[Internet Shortcut]` line, the `Exec=http://tune-in.com/radio/Country-Roads-s224628/` line is absolutely wrong. Please just copy/paste from my answer.

Comment: I am a Windows person trying to switch some of my systems over to Linux and I am currently working with the Xtra-pc 64 flash drive that uses Ubuntu. I have been adding additional applications and fixing the applications that don't work right, I pasted your text into Notepad and moved it over to my Xtra-pc Desktop and it works now. Thanks. Once the desktop Icons work I can no longer edit them in gedit all I can do then is look at the properties. Why is that?

Comment: @RobMit In that case consider ["accepting" the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so that others may more easily find it in the future.

Comment: @RobMit Once you have fixed the file, it became a proper launcher. Nautilus (file manager app which also provides the desktop icons) is unaware to the fact that gedit can also handle  launchers, that's why you don't see a "open with gedit" option. To open and edit the launcher with gedit, first launch gedit, the hit <Ctrl>+<O> and select the launcher (note that it would look like `Country Roads.desktop` in the "open file" dialogue, won't show up as `Link to Country Roads`).