# "Invalid desktop entry file" when using "Type=Link" in .desktop files on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, .desktop, url

I'm having problems creating a shortcut file to webpages using `Type=Link` in a `.desktop` file, on Lubuntu 20.04

#### Problem

When clicking on a `.desktop` file with content like this ..

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=Name of Link Shortcut
URL=https://askubuntu.com
```

.. I get the following error message:

[image: invalid-desktop-entry-file]

#### What I've tried

- Making the file executable with `sudo chmod a+x [filename]` --- result: same issue
- Adding `Version=1.0` or `Version=1.1` --- result: same issue
- Adding `Encoding=UTF-8` --- result: same issue
- Using different values for the `URL` key --- result: same issue
- Changing the file suffix to `.url` --- result: nothing happens when trying to open the file

I've also run `desktop-file-validate` which does not give any errors or warnings (except when i include the "Encoding" key)

After searching I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073824/360991) but it gives me the same issue that I describe above

---

My OS is Lubuntu 20.04, but I think I recall having the same problem on Lubuntu 18.04

---

Specification document for .desktop files: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

Comment: I'm adding the Lubuntu manual page just for reference - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I found is to directly use the `.desktop` entry as firefox application:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Open Askbuntu
Exec=firefox https://askubuntu.com
```

Lxqt seems to take the `URL` key as a *file browser* path:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=Open Askbuntu
URL=/home
```

Opens the file browser at `/home` path. Must be a bug? Or some obscure misconfiguration.

Comment: This is the correct solution (or using `xdg-open` in lieu of `firefox`) for everything preceeding Groovy, i.e. with libfm-qt < 0.15.0. There was indeed a bug found and fixed. More info and discussion in [the commit message](https://github.com/lxqt/libfm-qt/commit/f0160ba5813c6164e96033ed2de4e2cba1ef7eb9) as well as the attached [issue](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues/1065).

As an aside, Bionic, being LXDE and having libfm (not libfm-qt), should not have the same problem.